# How to populate the property values of an object from its base object

Tags: c#, properties, populate

I have a class called BaseClass which has many properties of various types including lists and dictionaries. This class has three derived classes that have a few more properties in them. These classes are already used in a big application so changing the design is not doable at the moment.

So the derived classes are like:

```
public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass3 : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
}
```

I need to perform polymorphism when I de-serialize these classes based on a property that resides in the base class. So every time the Json object is deserialized to BaseClass, I need to check that property value and create the correct concrete class. To do this I need a method like PopulateFrom(this BaseClass instance, BaseClass fromObject) so I can call it this way:

```
var deserializedObjet = Serializer.Deserialize(jsonString);
switch(deserializedObjet.ConcreteType)
{
    case 1:
      return new DerivedClass1().PopulateFrom(deserializedObjet );
     case 2: 
      return new DerivedClass2().PopulateFrom(deserializedObjet );
     case 3: 
      return new DerivedClass3().PopulateFrom(deserializedObjet );
}
```

The derived classes have no data in the Json string. What they do is that they get the same data but they perform different operations on them or they represent them in a different way so I just need to deserialize the Json to the BaseClass.

I know StackTrace.Text has a similar method but that method was added as of version 4 which is not free.

Comment: If you deserialize the JSON to `BaseClass` then it will ignore the serialized values of the properties of the derived classes. You need to deserialize again to the correct class once you have figured out which one it is.

Comment: Sorry I probably did not mention the issue properly. The derived classes have no data in the Json string. What they do is that they get the same data but they perform different operations on them or they represent them in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a required class instance, copy property values from current base instance to the newly created one with reflection. Please find sample below (it have to be fixed before compile)

```
static void PopulateFrom(this BaseClass dest, BaseClass source) //extension method will not modify legacy code and can be added to the any static class
{
     var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties(public only);
     foreach (var pi in properties)
        if (pi.CanRead && pi.CanWrite)
          pi.SetValue(dest, pi.GetValue(source, null), null); //this will work only for classes inherited from BaseClass
}
```

Also you can override assignment operator in BaseClass and copy property values with it.

Comment: @Aref sure! You will get destination object with List1 (or Array2) property that points to the same List1 (or Array2) property as source object e.g. However I'd like to note that it is not possible to serialize Dictionary and you have to add fake KeyValuePair<int, string>[] property to get dictionary serialized with XmlSerializer